# If two columns are 1 then make new column

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i need a my sql statement which selects something similar to this

```
SELECT present, wholeday, attendance
```

`present` and `wholeday` is given, while attendance is generated by a combination of present and wholeday

```
if present == 1 and wholeday == 1 then attendance = 1

if present == 1 and wholeday == 0 then attendance = .5

if present == 0 and wholeday == 0 then attendance = 0
```

Comment: So you want us to help you without any effort from your side?

Comment: You already have the logic, what's holding you back from writing the SQL query?

Comment: Since there's no case for present=0, wholeday=1, `(present + wholeday)/2.0` should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query would be:

```
SELECT PRESENT, WHOLEDAY,
       CASE
           WHEN  (PRESENT = 1 AND WHOLEDAY = 1) THEN 1
           WHEN  (PRESENT = 1 AND WHOLEDAY = 0) THEN 0.5
           ELSE  0
       END as ATTENDANCE 
FROM MY_TABLE
```

[Case](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/) Syntax is :

```
CASE
    WHEN condition_1 THEN commands
    WHEN condition_2 THEN commands
    ...
    ELSE commands
END CASE;
```